# Visual block insert/append doesn't work

Tags: vim

I select a block of text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, but when I then type <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>, my vim editor goes into insert mode on only the location where I began the visual block mode.

For example,

```
Here
is 
text
```

I want

```
#Her 
#is 
#text
```

but I get:

```
#Here
is 
text
```

Comment: That's perfectly normal.

Comment: I had this problem.  It could be your Ctrl-V is being intercepted and transformed at the GUI level.  Your terminal program might be trapping the Ctrl-V and changing it to something else before vim even sees it.  For me it turns out what happened long ago I had fiddled with the Konsole shortcut keys and remapped Ctrl-V to Shift+ins for compatibility issues.  To fix, I went to konsole -> settings -> configure shortcuts -> remove the remap of Ctrl-V to Shift+ins.  A way to prove if this is the case is to use vim to remap a different keystroke to Ctrl-V in the vimrc to bypass the intercept.

Comment: Same issue for me, using zsh on a Mac, and none of the answers below work.  I can use Ctrl-V just fine, and often do, but Shift-i kicks me out of Visual mode and into ordinary (not multi-line) insert mode.

Comment: Make sure you do your block selection by some sort of movement (movement counts, movement to match etc). If you use a text object to highlight the block, then I observe this behaviour where it just reverts to inserting at the original cursor position.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>-> select the block -> press <kbd>I</kbd> -> type <kbd>#</kbd>

**then press <kbd>ESC</kbd>**

more detail:

```
:h v_b_I
```

you can see:

```
Visual-block Insert                     *v_b_I* 

With a blockwise selection, I{string}<ESC> will insert {string} at the start 
of block on every line of the block, provided that the line extends into the block.
```

Comment: Note that the default vim installed with Ubuntu 14.04 (installed as `vi`) does not include the `visualextra` feature, so block insert won't work there. `sudo apt-get install vim` brings in a more full-featured version, on which `visualextra` is activated. You can check the output of `vim --version` to see the full list of activated features.

Comment: `esc` was the key.  I've been using C_c to escape insert mode.  :|

Comment: Note "**wait 1 second** and the inserted text will appear on every line"

Comment: i got to `press I (shift + i)` step in `zsh`, it seems to only be only editing one line for some reason

Comment: ok it seems to only take in effect after i click `Esc` after the edit, is there anyway to have vim displaying the multi column editting change in realtime

Comment: NOTE: Make sure you do your block selection by some sort of movement (movement counts, movement to match etc). If you use a text object to highlight the block, then I observe this behaviour where it just reverts to inserting at the original cursor position rather than doing your S-I insert on each line, or your S-A append. I now use `/^$<enter-key>k` to match until the next blank line (the k is needed, or else your insert/append ends up on the blank line also.

Comment: Also, the convenient `<S-v>}` to select to the next blank line fails as well, as using `ap` or `ip`

Answer (score 34):

Make sure you exit visual block with <kbd>ESC</kbd>, not <kbd>Ctrl C</kbd>.

Also, Vim does not live update in visual block mode, you have to leave visual block mode to show the changes on other lines.

You will only see:

```
#Here
is 
text
```

After you enter visual block and insert a `#`, but once you leave visual block mode pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> it should look like:

```
#Here
#is 
#text
```

Answer (score 9):

For me the problem was that I was using linewise visual mode (i.e. enter visual mode by pressing `V`), rather than blockwise visual mode (i.e. enter visual mode by using `Ctrl-v`).  Also note that you have to exit visual mode by using `<Esc>` (or equivalently by using `Ctrl-[` on English keyboards) rather than by using `Ctrl-c`.

Comment: yes! if you see "-- VISUAL LINE --" text in the bottom line, it will not work. Use CTRL+V instead

Comment: Me too, Vim has three visual mode `-- VISUAL --`,`-- VISUAL LINE --` and `-- VISUAL BLOCK --`, <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>I</kbd> only for `-- VISUAL BLOCK --` .

Answer (score 0):

```
rpm -qa | grep vim

vim-enhanced-7.4.160-1.el7.x86_64
vim-common-7.4.160-1.el7.x86_64
vim-filesystem-7.4.160-1.el7.x86_64

1/just remove vi and use vim instead
or
2/alias vim='vi' in your bashrc
or
3/ln -s $(which vim) $(which vim|sed 's/vim/vi/g')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and I'm not sure if it's because I'm on Mac OSX. I thought I needed to hit Esc twice. However, once you hit ESC it takes a second for it to place all the characters.

In the example below I ran the following commands:

```
Ctrl + v
6
j
Shift + i
#
space
Esc
```

Here's a screen recording of how it looks:

[vim visual insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXlfk.gif)