# Visual block insert in redhat vim

Tags: vim

My ec2 server came with redhat vim:

```
[ec2-user@****** ~]$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Jul  7 2012 08:03:48)
Included patches: 1-411
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
```

I've read the [wikia doc](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Inserting_text_in_multiple_lines) and many posts such as:

- [Vim: How to insert in visual block mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399572/vim-how-to-insert-in-visual-block-mode)
- [Visual block insert/append doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925932/visual-block-insert-append-doesnt-work)

All of the guide told me to do `Ctrl+V`, select the area, then `Shift+i`, type the character to be inserted, and `ESC`. This doesn't work for me.

I can however do `:s/^/\` and this will insert a space in front of each line, but **how can I insert it in somewhere in the middle?**

For example, I want to insert several spaces to turn

```
hello world
a cute cat
milky way
```

into

```
hello     world
a cut     e cat
milky     way
```

In one visual block operation

Comment: what exactly are you looking for? may be a sample of your input & expected output will help.

Comment: What *do* you get?  Note that it is normal to see the change on just the active line until you are done and type ESC.  If you `:set showmode` then vim should confirm that you are actually in Visual Block mode after CTRL-V.

Comment: Note that the default vim installed with Ubuntu 14.04 (installed as vi) does not include the visualextra feature, so block insert won't work there. sudo apt-get install vim brings in a more full-featured version, on which visualextra is activated. This may also be a problems on RedHat. You can check the output of vim --version to see the full list of activated features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution to your updated question:

1. Go between "hello" & "world" on first line
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> to enter visual block mode.
3. Go down using `2j` to select that column
4. Press <kbd>I</kbd>   #An uppercase `I`
5. Press 4 spaces to get the desired output.
6. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Here's a small demo:

[image: demo gif]

Comment: Note that the default vim installed with Ubuntu 14.04 (installed as `vi`) does not include the `visualextra` feature, so block insert won't work there. `sudo apt-get install vim` brings in a more full-featured version, on which `visualextra` is activated. This may also be a problems on RedHat. You can check the output of `vim --version` to see the full list of activated features.

Answer (score 1):

Visual-block Insert is what you are trying to do with `Shift+i`. It is a blockwise operator

```
:h blockwise-operators
```

Blockwise operators are not available when vim is compiled without the +visualextra feature.

To check if you have this feature

```
:version
```

If you do not, then you may have to use the methods suggested in the other answers or, get another version of vim.

Comment: Probably one more line of the "vim --version" output would have been enough:  if it says "Tiny version", then it is missing a lot of features that we expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a regex style answer try (matches what Visual-Block mode would have done):

```
:%s;\v^(.{5})(.*);\1    \2;g
```

To match your expected output:

```
:%s;\v^(.{5})\s*(.*);\1    \2;g
```

If you need this done only on lines 1 through 3:

```
:1,3s;\v^(.{5})(.*);\1    \2;g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `:10,20s/^/ /`, insert space only for line 10-20