# How to edit blocks in vim without visual block mode

Tags: vim

Is there a way to edit a vertical block in a code without using the visual block mode selection?

Comment: What exactly do you attempt to achieve? Your question sounds very hypothetical.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve? Why would visual block selection not work in that case?

Comment: Actually, I wanna try to not use the visual mode whereever possible to be more productive. That would work for line wise visual mode, but i'm curious about blocks in that case.

Comment: What's so unproductive about visual mode? It's just one more key [combination] to enter it.

Comment: Well yes, that's true, but you're actually faster when not selecting the stuff you wanna edit first. Instead one is faster when using command line commands (that's at least what I've read in some articles, so don't get me wrong, I <3 visual block mode)

Comment: You can use the [textobj-word-column.vim](https://github.com/coderifous/textobj-word-column.vim). However I must warn you that it doesn't work in all scenarios, because the way it guesses at word boundaries.

Comment: `^V9j` is *about* as fast as `:.,+9`, even if you can think of the right regular expression fast enough…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's so bad about *blockwise visual mode*?! There's no practical alternative to it.

- You could use `:substitute` with atoms like `\%>v`, `\%<v`, `\%>l` and `\%<l` to limit the pattern match to a rectangular block, but that's very tedious.
- There are some multi-edit plugins (inspired by other editors) that allow you to select some areas, and then simultaneously edit them all.
- For special purposes, you could write a scriptlet / mapping with `getline()` / `setline()` and String manipulation in Vimscript.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ingo's answer, I'll add this: Ex commands are *line-wise* by design. The nature of the visual mode doesn't matter: Ex commands will *always* use the first line and the last line of your selection as range by default anyway.

Because it's not line-wise, visual-block mode and block "thinking" doesn't really align with Ex commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to this recent answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22238813/3130080

For example,

```
:%s/\%6c/x/
```

will insert "x" before the 6'th character in each line, and

```
:1,2s/\%>1c\%<4c.//g
```

will delete characters 2 and 3 in lines 1 and 2.

```
:help /\%c
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please do not misuse the existing duplicate handling system which is flags. If you think the question is already answered, select the duplicate reason when flagging. You also have enough reputation for that. With this reply, you are basically encouraging the OPs to ask the same question again and again without searching.

Comment: @LaszloPapp:  Thanks for the advice.  Although the answer I linked to is appropriate for this question, I do not think the two questions are that similar.  This one asks how to avoid using Visual-block mode, and the other one asks why Visual-block mode is not working as expected.

Comment: Then just drop the link if it does not answer the question, and write a correct answer.