# Vim block visual mode insert not working

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and visual block insertion isn't working for me.

I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> then I select my block using arrow keys, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> but it only inserts a character at the top most like:

```
*
*
*
*
```

to

```
asdf*
*
*
*
```

I have read [prepend to visual block not working in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303792/prepend-to-visual-block-not-working-in-vim) and

```
:echo has('visualextra')
```

returns `1`.

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

points out that vim is the newest version installed.

Any ideas about what's wrong?

Comment: What you have done is correct. can you print the output of vim --version here? Also, give a multiple lines of text as example.

Comment: // only inserts a character at the top most // You can insert/delete only at the start/end of the topmost line. It will be applied same way for following lines. You want some thing different?

Comment: Do you press `<Esc>` after `asdf`?

Comment: does this solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925932/visual-block-insert-append-doesnt-work/14925977#14925977

Answer (score 3):

As romanl pointed, you need to press `<Esc>` after inserting the text. 
Otherwise, you are pretty much correct.